# Product Catalog not available on CD

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We are using Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 and CD and CM are on two different servers. CM is working perfectly fine and we are able to see the product catalog data on CM but it is not displaying on CD server.

The product catalog is in the published state.

I believe some configurations are missing. Please somebody can point out what configurations are missing?

It would be a great help if you can provide some pointer area as well.

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Did you check logs files ? Do you have Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DataProvider.config file in \Include\Y.Commerce.Engine folder?

Comment: Yes, this file is available on both the server and I did not find any difference in the files.

I did not find any error entry inside the log file

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore Commerce product team plans to provide fully supported scaled topology documentation with the 9.1 release.

Sitecore Community prepared two scaled installations for installing Sitecore Commerce 9.0.2 in a Scaled Deployment, based on Sitecore’s XP1 topology.

They are located on Github:

https://github.com/CommerceMinion/Sitecore-v902-XP1-Scaled-Installation

https://github.com/CommerceMinion/Sitecore-Commerce-v902-Scaled-Installation

Note: These are not officially supported by Sitecore Support